# How to add padding to gradient <shape> in Android?

Tags: android

I have a shape with a gradient that I'm using as a divider between `ListView` items.  I've defined it as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

<gradient
    android:startColor="#ccd0d3"
    android:centerColor="#b6babd"
    android:endColor="#ccd0d3"
    android:height="1px"
    android:angle="0" />

</shape>
```

I would like to add 6 pixels of padding on either side of the gradient, so that it doesn't extend from edge to edge of the screen.

However, no matter where I put an `android:left="6px"` and `android:right="6px"`, it doesn't seem to take effect.  I can put it in the `<shape>` element, the `<gradient>` element, or in a separate `<padding>` child of `<shape>`, and it doesn't change anything.

How can I add padding on the left and right of my list divider?

Comment: I've updated all the answers to use dp not px since most of the time developers should be using dp to take into account different screen densities: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: In addition to comments and solutions saying not to use px, use dp - I would like to add that gradient has no height attribute and is useless in this case. Height should be applied as an attribute of a <size> element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Padding doesn't affect <shape> in an XML Layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283085/padding-doesnt-affect-shape-in-an-xml-layout)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

One solution seems to be to "wrap" my drawable with another drawable that specifies the appropriate padding.

For example, `list_divider.xml` would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:left="6dp"
        android:right="6dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_divider_inner" />

</layer-list>
```

And then `list_divider_inner.xml` would be the original drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

<gradient
    android:startColor="#ccd0d3"
    android:centerColor="#b6babd"
    android:endColor="#ccd0d3"
    android:height="1px"
    android:angle="0" />

</shape>
```

This results in two files to specify a simple divider though.  I don't know if there's a way to do it with only one file though.

Comment: <sarcam>px will look *great* an a modern xhdpi phone.</sarcam> — Don't use px **ever**. Use **dp** for graphics and **sp** for font sizes instead. Read: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: @Martin I've updated the answer to use dp to avoid copy and pasting of bad practices.

Comment: This question was about using a fine divider between list view items.  For this particular situation, i did specifically want to use a single pixel divider no matter what the resolution of the device, so px was correct.

Comment: This is the best solution i'v looking for! I'v just needed to add padding to native divider, thus I wrap `"@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_dark"` into layer-list container. Thanx!

Comment: Thanks For some reason inset doesn't work in android 4.2.2. Only this solution works.

Answer (score 141):

I guess you could combine it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:left="6dp"
          android:right="6dp">

        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient android:startColor="#ccd0d3"
                      android:centerColor="#b6babd"
                      android:endColor="#ccd0d3"
                      android:height="1px"
                      android:angle="0"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: This solution is better because it only uses one file.

Comment: Works wonderfully with the slightest change:
android:right="6px" />
should be 
android:right="6px" >

Comment: Note: The padding does not affect the content of the view. If you use this for an editText, the edge will overdraw the 1st letter of the text.

Comment: Great, now, how can I use this with my selector?

Comment: @Martin unless you are using a height of 1px for a list divider. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979218/android-listview-divider

Comment: what if I also want top and bottom padding?

Comment: This actually adds a Margin not Padding.

Comment: @Martin gonna look, how bulky your dp-defined separator will look like at the low-density screen.

Answer (score 55):

Another solution using inset:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:insetLeft="6dp"
    android:insetRight="6dp" >

    <shape   
        android:shape="rectangle">

    <gradient
        android:startColor="#ccd0d3"
        android:centerColor="#b6babd"
        android:endColor="#ccd0d3"
        android:height="1px"
        android:angle="0" />

    </shape>

</inset>
```

Comment: @ntrications: no need to edit, I use px instead dp here because the questioner want that.

Comment: This way, you could have it in the selector file as well.

Comment: perfect. just what I needed.