# What is a divider color attribute in ListView?

Tags: android, user-interface

I want to create a divider, which would look exactly like a divider in ListView and will depend on a current theme.

```
<View android:id="@+id/first_line"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_below="@+id/description"
          android:layout_height="1dp"
          android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
          android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"/>
```

Which attribute should I specify in this line `android:background="attr/colorPrimaryDark"` to handle this?

Comment: "?android:attr/colorPrimaryDark"

Comment: colorPrimaryDark is not related to ListView divider's color

Comment: you want just a customize devider? try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620685/custom-style-listdivider

Comment: No, i want to create a divider in RelativeLayout, which will look like a standard divider in ListView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check android styles file. 
Divider in ListView it's a drawable. 
For example:

```
<style name="Widget.ListView" parent="Widget.AbsListView">
    <item name="listSelector">@drawable/list_selector_background</item>
    <item name="cacheColorHint">?attr/colorBackgroundCacheHint</item>
    <item name="divider">@drawable/divider_horizontal_dark_opaque</item>
</style>
```

So you can create a View:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/my_divider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_dark"/>
```

See the drawable from same theme that your app(for example).