# How to get drawable divider between Grid View Rows?

Tags: android, gridview, divider

i want to know if there is any way to display a drawable file in between the grid view rows ?(only rows)   I want to get the layout in the following way

[image]

i used grid view to display books and i have divider in drawable folder and i need to show it in the that way

i searched a lot but every thing just says how to give color divider between rows but i need to display the divider from drawable

is there any way to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android gridview row dividers / separators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12109126/android-gridview-row-dividers-separators)

Answer (score -1):

You can define custom divider, check code snippet below:

```
 <GridView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:divider="@drawable/divider"
android:dividerHeight="3sp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

where divider is your custom drawable image. You can also check this link for more clarification:
[custom divider](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9620895/6202040)

Comment: Dude, you can't say divider in a grid view. Seriously, get out of here.