# How to change the default divider color for all ListViews

Tags: android, coding-style, android-widget, android-styles

I am trying to apply default styling for all the listViews from style.xml

Please note at some places I am using nested listViews.

In **style.xml**

```
    <style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.ForceOverflow">
           <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
           <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/awesomeListViewStyle</item>
    </style>



<style name="awesomeListViewStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
        <item name="android:fadingEdge">none</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/orange</item>
<item name="android:divider">#EEEEEE</item>
    </style>
```

This has no effect. In the Manifest Theme.MyTheme as my default theme.
Please advice :)

Comment: try this link and answer of mike -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979218/android-listview-divider

Comment: you are missing "android:dividerHeight" item

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979218/android-listview-divider) as Bhavin and Mark pointed out, in your style you should also add

```
<item name="android:dividerHeight">1px</item>
```