# Set thickness and color for all ListViews in app

Tags: android, listview

This is a follow up question to this question:
[How to change the default divider color for all ListViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028246/how-to-change-the-default-divider-color-for-all-listviews)

I got a style which has the `android:divider` and `android:dividerHeight` set. This style is used in the manifest as a style for the application.

The problem is that the divider does not change at all. It does work if I set these attributes directly to each ListView's attributes but not if I throw the attributes in a style. What is the correct way to set these divider's attributes for all ListViews in the app?

This is the style:

```
<style name="MyListView">
   <item name="android:dividerHeight">2px</item>
   <item name="android:divider">#EEEEEE</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I didn't add `parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView"` to the `style` tag. It should be like this:

```
<style name="MyListView" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
```