# How to give background or space  between list view row and avoid click event in android

Tags: android

How to give space or background or divider between list view for one row in android.I have implemented onitem click in list view.if user click  background or space or divider the how to avoid click event for backgroud?.can anybody tell how to do?
Thanks

Comment: This question is weirdly worded. What do you mean by space between `ListView` row? Between it vertically?

Comment: Use android:divider property.

Answer (score 0):

use Android ListView Divider

```
<ListView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/cashItemsList"
     android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
     android:divider="@drawable/list_divider" android:dividerHeight="1dp"></ListView>
```

or

[Android ListView Divider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979218/android-listview-divider)

Created res/drawable/divider.xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient android:startColor="#ffcdcdcd" android:endColor="#ffcdcdcd" android:angle="270.0" />
</shape>
```

And in styles.xml for listview item, I added the following lines:

```
<item name="android:divider">@drawable/divider</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
```

Comment: i want for one row and avoid click event for background

Comment: ok if there is 10 rows then you only need it (space) for 3rd row like ?

Comment: are you want same as in above statement ?

Comment: so you can do that in get view just add the padding if row 3rd ..... need to handle more if you are using convert view