# Is there a way to keep the dividers around a non selectable preference?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, preferenceactivity, listpreference

If you set the [selectability](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#attr_android:selectable) of a [preference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html) item to false, you will notice that the dividers around that item will disappear.

Do you know if there is a way to keep those dividers?

I have looked at the ListView API and could not find a solution that could be applied here, since there is no selectable attribute for ListView items (except for the [headers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29) and [footers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29)).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I did it with a hack.

```
<Preference android:layout="@layout/preference_divider" />
<Preference android:title="@string/whatever" android:selectable="false" />
```

res/layout/preference_divider.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<View xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#cccccc"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1px" />
```

Comment: Why did you change it to 1px? 0px works fine for me, just wondering if there may be problems with 0px on some devices or Android versions?

Answer (score 0):

some example code would help! did you set your dividers in the `ListView` element? if yes check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979218/android-listview-divider) as well.

```
<ListView
    //...
    android:divider="@color/black"
    />
```

Otherwise you could create a custom ListElementView and add your dividers in the layout xml.

Comment: I am not saying that my list of preferences item doesn't have dividers at all. I am saying, that the items which are made *non selectable* end up with no dividers around them. There is nothing special about the code, since it works as the framework intended it. I am just looking for a way to customize this default experience. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a "trick" that worked for me. Simply set android:focusable="true"
 to any of the items inside the preference. This will make the whole preference line not clickable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the preference to show some text you can also use an uneditable EditTextPreference.
The preference will still be selectable but only shows its content when selected.

```
<EditTextPreference
    android:editable="false"
    ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

The line you want to hide is called 'divider'. `PreferenceActivity` extends `ListActivity` and as you may expect it uses `ListView`. You can change a divider in a `ListView`. In your `PreferenceActivity`:

```
        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        lv.setDividerHeight(0);
```