# Change listViewDivider padding, color and height programmatically

Tags: android, listview, divider

for my app I want to change the divider of a listView.
The goal is to set a solid padding and a User-definable height such as a User-definable color.

Therefore I have set up a custom divider drawable as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"

<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:insetLeft="20dp"
     android:insetRight="20dp"

     <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
          <solid android:color="@color/dark_grey" />
     </shape>

</inset>
```

This gives me one part of the desired result. The padding which I want to have. (And also a static custom color, but I want to have it user definable)

So my second approach was to set the divider programmatically:

```
int dividerColor = customColor;
int dividerHeight = customHeight;

myList.setDivider(new ColorDrawable (dividerColor));
myList.setDividerHeight(dividerHeight);
```

With this solution I get a customizable height and a customizable color but the divider is drawn from screenside to screenside without any padding.

So my question is:

Is there a way to either set the Padding to the divider programmatically or to access height and color of the drawable?

(!IMPORTANT) The Padding should only affect the Divider since I use a headerView which should cover the whole screenwidth.

**EDIT**: The perfect way would be to set everything programmatically.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you please refer  [Old Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979218/android-listview-divider)  from stack overflow,

It contains part of solutions.

Comment: I don't get you. The answers over there only show how to specify the divider in xml. But since I want to change it at Runtime these answers aren't a solution to my problem. But thanks for the suggestion anyway.