# How to add border to the bottom of list item in listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a list view and I want to add a bottom border to each list item so it acts as a separating line between all the cells.

This is my list view right now.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    >

....
.....
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 <ListView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="@color/red"
    android:dividerHeight="1px">
 </ListView>
```

and color value is inside colors.xml or strings.xml:

```
<color name="red">#FF0000</color>
```

P.S. I am using px on purpose [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12061612/435706)

Answer (score 0):

Create a `drawable` like this , and set it to the list `item background`. This will set border only for layout `bottom`.

```
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:top="-1dp" android:right="-1dp" android:left="-1dp">
    <shape >
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#FFFF" />
    </shape>
 </item>
</layer-list>
```

or you can also try to set a divider for `ListView`

```
  android:divider="#FFFF"
  android:dividerHeight="1dp"
```