# ListView divider is not dividng items

Tags: java, android

I have a listview:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="8dp"/>
```

And I also have a drawable to draw round corners for the listview items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="@color/listViewItemBackground"/>
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    <padding android:left="3dp" android:top="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:bottom="3dp" />
</shape>
```

With the above setup, the items are touching each other.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You've set `android:divider="@null"` so obviously you aren't seeing a divider.

Look at how [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979218/android-listview-divider) has set up their `ListView` divider for an example what you should be doing.

Answer (score 1):

try like below...

```
android:divider="@color/redBackground"
```

and color value is inside colors.xml:

```
<color name="redBackground">#C60202</color>
```

Please see below link for more details...

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#attr_android:divider

`android:divider`

Drawable or color to draw between list items.

May be a reference to another resource, in the form `"@[+][package:]type:name"` or to a theme attribute in the form `"?[package:][type:]name"`.

May be a color value, in the form of `"#rgb"`, `"#argb"`, `"#rrggbb"`, or `"#aarrggbb"`.

This corresponds to the global attribute resource symbol divider.