# Android: How do you stop custom buttons from taking all available cell space in a TableLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, custom-widgets

I designed coloured Android Button Drawables and put them in a TableLayout. The problem is that Android's default buttons do not take up the entire cell space, but my drawables do (See attatched pictures). How can I adjust my XML so that my drawables leave a bit of space like the default buttons? I've pasted the XML code at the bottom.

**Custom Buttons:**

[image: Custom buttons taking all available cell space]

**Default Buttons:**

[image: Default buttons leave gaps]

**XML CODE:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true"><shape>
            <gradient android:angle="90" android:endColor="@color/dark_red" android:startColor="@color/brick_red" />

            <corners android:radius="10dip" />

            <padding android:bottom="10dip" android:left="10dip" android:right="10dip" android:top="10dip"></padding>

        </shape></item>
    <item android:state_focused="true"><shape>
            <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="@color/dark_red" android:startColor="@color/brick_red" />

            <corners android:radius="10dip" />

            <padding android:bottom="10dip" android:left="10dip" android:right="10dip" android:top="10dip" />
        </shape></item>
    <item><shape>
            <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="@color/dark_red" android:startColor="@color/red" />

            <corners android:radius="10dip" />

            <padding android:bottom="5dip" android:left="5dip" android:right="5dip" android:top="5dip" />
        </shape></item>

</selector>
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Maybe you can try to move the padding from the selector to the actual views?

Comment: That would make more sense! Should have done that before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to use the Top, Left, Bottom and Right attributes of items ? See : [How to add padding to gradient <shape> in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622364/how-to-add-padding-to-gradient-shape-in-android)

Alternatively, in your final layout that uses the button, you could use the attribute : `android:layout_margin(Right,Left,Top,Bottom)`

Comment: That layout_margin did the trick. Is it possible to set the margin of the button within the Button's XML itself? I looked through the intellisense list of available settings, and I couldn't find it.

Comment: if you are thinking the selector xml, you would have to try to the android:top, android:left, android:bottom and android:right in the items tag of your selector xml. Or to make it cleaner, but with the overhead of creating a new file, create a button_with_padding.xml, add just one item referencing the xml you already have as the drawable and set the top, left, right, bottom value there.