# Divider won't show on ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-listfragment

Help! I tried all answers on SO but to no avail

Shape xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line">
    <!-- stroke width must be 1px, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979218/android-listview-divider -->  
    <stroke 
        android:width="1px"
        android:color="#aaAAaa" />  
</shape>
```

In ListFragment:

```
public void onViewCreated(View v, Bundle bundle){
  listView = getListView();
  listView.setDivider(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.xxxx));
  listView.setDividerHeight(1);
  setListAdapter(...);
}
```

Adapter:

```
@Override public boolean areAllItemsEnabled(){return true;}
```

Also, the divider should not span the entire listview's width, I want to have some padding on the left and right. So I think a shape drawable is a must.

**EDITED**  Answer:
Don't use line, use a rectangle instead.
and follow this for padding:
[How to add padding to gradient <shape> in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622364/how-to-add-padding-to-gradient-shape-in-android)

Comment: Try giving width to 1 dp for stroke. That might help, too.

Comment: Have you returned true from isEnabled? Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9196852/1777090). Might help.

Answer (score 0):

In xml of listview specify following :

```
 <ListView
        android:id="@+id/List"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:divider="#35FFFFFF"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" >
    </ListView>
```

The divider color and height can be anything that you want.

Comment: You can use somethinh like this,         lv = getListView();  lv.setDivider(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(android.R.color.black));
lv.setDividerHeight(1);

Comment: Just bear in mind that setDividerHeight works in px, not in dp. Some conversion is needed if you intend to use dps instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try using,

```
listView = getListView();
listView.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#aaAAaa")))
float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 1,getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
listView.setDividerHeight((int)px)
```

**P.S.** updated code to get dip value for given int value. You can pass the value on place where I've set `1`.

Comment: Just bear in mind that setDividerHeight works in px, not in dp. Some conversion is needed if you intend to use dps instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"   
    android:dividerHeight="3dp" 
    android:divider="#05806D"
    android:listSelector="#ffffff"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</ListView>
```

let me know till you get the solution or not ?