# Android recyclerView decorator padding

Tags: android, user-interface, kotlin

i am having a problem with a decorator in my project. 
This is what  i want to achieve :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WnyU.png

here is my divider xml :

```
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line">
    <solid android:color="@color/secondary_text" />
    <size android:height="1dp" />
    <padding
        android:left="8dp"
        android:right="8dp"/>
</shape>
```

Decorator implementation :

```
    recycler__transactions_activity.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(context,
                                      DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL).apply {
        setDrawable(drawable(R.drawable.divider))
    })
```

Can anyone spot a mistake please ?
EDITED : Problem is padding.  the line, which divide views is displayed without padding
This is result of my code https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3OGX.png
SOLUTION :
wrapping divider into another item

```
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:left="24dp"
    android:right="24dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/accent" />
        <size android:height="1dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Thanks guys :)

Comment: This is not very clear. What you are trying to achieve and what problem you are facing?

Comment: ok, it is edited :)

Comment: can you show the image, which has problem according to your code?

Comment: edited once again

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283085/padding-doesnt-affect-shape-in-an-xml-layout

Comment: Don'y you just need some padding inside each of your cells?

Comment: done by wrapping into another item. thanks guys. Padding is not good idea for future use in my app :) Thanks guys